# Not able to set Value propery of asp: textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using asp text box. In the code behind i.e in the cs page am not able to set the Value by id.Value="xy";

Please help me out.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TextBox` class has `Text` property.

Try,
Markup:

```
<asp:TextBox id="txt1" runat="server"/>
<asp:TextBox id="txt2" runat="server" Text="Hello"/>
```

Code behind:

```
txt1.Text="Hello";
```

Comment: I am using value property in .aspx page. So the same should be able to use in the CS also right? eg:<asp:TextBox ID="Amounttxt" runat="server" Width="100px" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);"
                                                                    Value="Amount" ForeColor="GrayText" OnClick="this.value = ''; this.style.color = 'black'"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: Use **Text** property instead of **Value**.

Comment: @Anjana - In markup, you may use **Text**  or **value** attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You should have your text box in .aspx page like below:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1"></asp:TextBox>
```

Then in your code behind page like this will do this:

```
TextBox1.Text = "your text here";
```

Answer (score 0):

see if it is label it is having a `value` property  to display text

```
 lbl.value ="labeltext"
```

if is textBox it is having a `Text` property to display text

```
 txt.Text ="textboxtext"
```

Comment: Ok Thanks Rachana for the comments:)